# How to do something on session start in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I need to initialize every new http session with some values. How do I do that?

I tried to create a session-scoped component and initializing session in @PostConstruct, but session-scoped beans are not eagerly created until I request access them.

Comment: If those initialized values are to be used by something else, surely it's good enough to have them initialized the first time they're referenced?

Comment: I have a bean which holds some user-session related values. I don't want to put initialization logic into that because it is a separate responsibility. Neither do I want to put the invocation of the initializing method in services which reference that session bean. I can not see a correct way of initialization on reference

Comment: Can you flesh this out into specific example code, showing how you'd like it to work? I have a suspicion this is rather easier than you think.

Answer (score 3):

If you are absolutely certain that your want eager initialization, you can do the following:

- define an interceptor for all beans
- defina a `<lookup-method>` for that interceptor:

  ```
  <lookup-method name="getCurrentSessionBean"
       bean="yourSessionBeanToInitialize"/>
  ```
- define the interceptor `abstract`, with an `abstract` method `getCurrentSessionBean()`
- create a flag `initialized` on the bean
- on each interception, call the lookup method and it will return an instance of the bean from the current session. If it is not initialized (the flag), initialize it
- you can also use `@PostConstruct` and spare the `initizlied` flag

Another option is to:

- define a `HttpSessionListener` in web.xml (or with annotations if using servlet 3.0)
- use `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext)` to obtain the context
- call `getBean(..)` to get an instance of the session-scoped bean
- it will be initialized with `@PostConstruct` at that point

The first option is "more spring", the second is easier and faster to implement.

Comment: In method 2 where do I get servletContext?

Comment: Got it: HttpSessionEvent.getSession().getServletContext()

Comment: I use an aop-proxied session-scoped bean UserInfo to hold user session information. The problem is that the instance of UserInfo I get in the  session listener is different from the one I get in my controller. I guess this may be a problem of different contexts but I am not sure